# POST (HTTP) + jQuery: How can I send specific form data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, httprequest

I'm trying to figure out how I can send a specific form data **fname[name]**

**jQuery code:**

```
FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
    if(info.status == 204)
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'https://domain.com/file-uploaded.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                fname: file
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Chrome Developer Tools:**

[image: http post]

(here you can see it's sending multiple form data, I want to send only fname[name])

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you performing this function on submit()?

Comment: hmm I'm not using submit() it's plupload plugin, maybe it can help you http://screencast.com/t/JI8soelA

Comment: file here looks like it is an object containing various attribute, pick the one you want to send like `file.name`

Comment: oh, it works, thank you Quince!! it was very simple! post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file here looks like it is an object containing various properties, pick the one you want to send like;

```
FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
    if (info.status == 204) {
        jQuery.ajx({
            url: "address_to_send_data_to",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                //file is an object so access the property desired
                fname: file.name
            }
        });
    }
}
```